Unable to reflect UTC coverage on the coverage/index.html page using Rspec ( uses Forest Admin )
Unable to reflect UTC coverage on the coverage/index.html page using Rspec in Ruby on rails, except the test_setup_db.rake file nothing is covered even after writing valid test cases ( using simple cov ). The service is for using the forest admin.
gems used for testing
gem 'faker'                     
  gem 'simplecov'                 # to track code coverage
  gem 'json_expressions'          
  gem 'mocha'                     
  gem 'webmock'                  
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.0.3'    
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-sonarqube-formatter', '~> 1.5', require: false

Tried running the coverage test for other services which is working perfectly fine as I'm able to reflect the coverage on the coverage page for different services which does not use forest admin.

Hey :wave: and welcome to SO.
Could you provide more informations on what you are trying to achieve (Code sample, command you run, ...) ?

Command : rspec  spec
Code Sample :
